# RxSwift, RxCocoa and UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, rx-swift

I have a problem with implementing a UITableView using RxSwift.

I tried to bind an observable of an array of models to the table items with the following code.
`models.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Cell", cellType: ModelTableViewCell.self`.

But when I do it gives me the following error: `Type 'inout UITableView' does not conform to protocol 'ReactiveCompatible'` and I know the error can't be right because NSObject extends ReactiveCompatible so UITableView also does. Also, my project code isn't really different than the examples shown on [RxSwiftCommunity](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources)

I created a small example project that has the error.

[image: [Example code showing the error (picture)]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift is quite good language but sometimes happens moments when compiler couldn't recognize the type of parameters. Then you need to explicit define a type of arguments. In your case you need to define the type of block arguments, see the code:

```
func bindRx(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    viewModel.models.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: ModelTableViewCell.ReuseIdentifier,
                                                 cellType: ModelTableViewCell.self)) { (_, model: Model, cell: ModelTableViewCell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = model.name
    }
    .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

[image]

Comment: What if i want to bind for custom label ? , this piece of code works for UitableviewCell not for Custom tableview Cell

Comment: There is custom cell type `ModelTableViewCell `  in my code example

Comment: You can extend it by adding Outlet

`class ModelTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet var myLabel: MyCustomLabel!
}`